# Value Type vs Ref Type for structures

Tags: c#, value-type, ref, reference-type

According to MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx

Value Types: "All structures, even if their members are reference types"

However I did a small experiment in C#, where I had a structure with an array type, and an integer type. I instantiated the struct in the main method, then passed that struct to another method and messed with it. When I returned to the main method, the integer change was not reflected, but the array  changes were reflected. If I were looking at the individual data types (arrays are reference types and integers are value types) this would make sense.

However according to the wording of MSDN are structures with all it's data supposed to be value types? Am I missing something here... can structure data be both value types and reference types?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The statement is accurate - the `struct` itself is a value type.  The array that it has as a member is a reference type, which means it's a pointer to an address.  Therefore if you alter the contents of the array that is contained in the `struct`, then you are altering the memory allocated for this array directly.

As you noted, an integer in the `struct` was not modified.  Also, if you had altered the reference to the array in the `struct`, it would not have reflected the change.

For example:

```
struct MyStruct 
{
    public int[] AnArray;
}

int Main()
{
    MyStruct aStruct = new MyStruct();
    aStruct.AnArray = new int[3];
    AlterStruct(aStruct);
    Console.WriteLine(aStruct.AnArray.Length == 3);  // true
}

void AlterStruct(MyStruct aStruct)
{
    aStruct.AnArray = new int[5];
}
```